# Return Duplicate emails along with User Ids that are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I'm running into an issue with a duplicate query and I hope you guys can help.
Essentially what I want to do is find and list of the duplicate emails associated with different userids

My query is:

```
select UserId, acitveid, email, userstatusid
from (select  u.UserId, u.acitveid, cd.email, u.userstatusid,
            count(*)over (partition by cd.email) as cnt
            from ContactDetails cd 
            join  UserContactDetails ucd on ucd.ContactDetailsId = cd.ContactDetailsId
            join  dbo.[User] u on u.UserId = ucd.UserId ) ua
    where cnt >1
```

The issue I have with the above query is that it is returning the same userids for some of the results so it looks like:

```
Userid   AcitveId      email          UserStatusid
123      1             abc@123.com     1
123      1             abc@123.com     1
135      1             efg@123.com     1
142      1             efg@123.com     1
```

The results Im looking for are simply:

```
Userid   AcitveId      email          UserStatusid
135      1             efg@123.com     1
142      1             efg@123.com     1
```

Comment: Have you tried "select distinct..."

Comment: What happened to `UserId` `123`?

Comment: Without sample input data we are likely to only be able to guess here.

Comment: The two `UserID = 123` rows would be omitted because they are not duplicate emails across **different** users. It is the same user with the same email address listed twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH base AS (
SELECT DISTINCT u.UserId
        ,u.acitveid
        ,cd.email
        ,u.userstatusid
        ,
    FROM ContactDetails cd
    JOIN UserContactDetails ucd ON ucd.ContactDetailsId = cd.ContactDetailsId
    JOIN dbo.[User] u ON u.UserId = ucd.UserId
)
,duplicate_emails AS (
    SELECT email
        ,count(userId) AS cnt
    FROM base
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING count(userId) > 1
)
SELECT b.*
FROM base b
JOIN duplicate_emails de ON b.email = de.email
```

Answer (score 0):

A self join across Email = email and id <> id would work fine here. That said, your request and `lack of sample data` means that we are largely guessing based off the query and sample output you have provided. The below should get you pretty close and, if you update your OP, I am sure we can get you exactly what you're after.

```
SELECT ActiveUser.UserID Active_UserID,
    ActiveUser.ActiveID Active_ActiveID,
    ContactDetails.email AS Email,
    DuplicateUser.UserID AS Dup_UserID,
    DuplicateUser.ActiveID As Dup_ActiveID
FROM ContactDetails INNER JOIN 
    ContactDetails AS Duplicate ON ContactDetails.email = Duplicate.email AND ContactDetails.UserID <> Duplicate.UserID INNER JOIN
    UserContactDetails AS ActiveUserContactDetails ON ActiveUserContactDetails.ContactDetailsID = ContactDetails.ContactDetailsID INNER JOIN
    dbo.[User] AS ActiveUser ON ActiveUser.UserID = ActiveUserContactDetails.UserID INNER JOIN
    UserContactDetails AS DuplicateUserContactDetails ON DuplicateUserContactDetails.ContactDetailsID = Duplicate.ContactDetailsID INNER JOIN
    dbo.[User] AS DuplicateUser ON DuplicateUser.UserID = UserContactDetails.UserID
```